# How to "npm install" only when the package being installed is not current

Tags: npm

How can I make so `npm install package` will only install the package if there is a newer package in the npm registry.

I mean that it won't even check the dependencies but only the main package I want.

Comment: Did npm update package work for you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`npm update package` should do this.

Comment: Thanks for the backticks, I'll remember that one!

Comment: Thanks! This works better but I really wanted to have one command that either installs / updates or does nothing, with this I need to also check whether the package is installed before I choose between install and update.

Comment: I'm not sure such a command exists, it may be something you'd have to write taking advantage of some of the npm commands available and scripting the results.  I usually make use of the package.json file for my projects so I can do npm update -d and npm install -d to update and install any packages specified in the package.json file.

Comment: Current docs state that `npm update` will install missing packages: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update

Comment: @SeánHayes ... well that sucks! Thanks for pointing it out.